# Handlebars nested iteration build-in helper - empty output

Tags: json, node.js, loops, helper, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use iteration helper inside another one. But the inner helper doesn't output anything.

That's the handlebars template :

```
{{#people}}
    <h4>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h4>
    {{#students}}
    <h3>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h3>
    {{/students}}
{{/people}}
```

And that is my JSON :

```
{
  people : [
    { firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz" },
    { firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Lerche" },
    { firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson" }
  ],
  students: [
    { firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Smith" },
    { firstName: "Dan", lastName: "Knight" },
    { firstName: "Griffin", lastName: "Smith" }
  ]
}
```

Whats the solution for this problem? 
Try the code online and fast here : http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `{{#people}}`...`{{/people}}` gives rise to three contexts:

```
{ firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz" },
{ firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Lerche" },
{ firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson" }
```

so there are no students in any of those contexts, which is why the inner expression `{{#students}}`...`{{/students}}` gives no output.

Can you elaborate on what it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi im working on shop project. I have 3 categories for mens clothing.
And im trying to add for each category its subcategories in the one div.
The example above if the same as in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Very much J P....your answer is great...
The right code is :

```
{
  people : [
    { firstName: "Yehuda", lastName: "Katz", students: [{ firstName1: "Mike", lastName1: "Smith"
}] },
    { firstName: "Carl", lastName: "Lerche", students: [{ firstName1: "Mike", lastName1: "Smith"
}]  },
    { firstName: "Alan", lastName: "Johnson", students: [{ firstName1: "Mike", lastName1: "Smith"
}]  }
  ],
}
```